# Azure DocumentDB .JSON have several levels when deserializing into a entity

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I'm trying to build a entity with several levels downs for example

```
Customer
|
|
AddressBook
|   |
|   |
|   AddressType (ENUM)
|
|
PhoneBook
|  |
|  |
|  PhoneType (ENUM)
|
|
BillInformation
```

Will a JSON tree such as the one above deserialize successful into a Entity?
How Fast would be the retrive of such data from Azure DocumentDB?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can have JSON documents with any depth. There is no performance or serialization impact in retrieval or query due to the level of nesting. DocumentDB guarantees read latency of < 10ms at the 99th percentile, regardless of the nesting structure.

If you'd like to know how, you can read about how DocumentDB treats hierarchical JSON documents as trees for storage/indexing here: http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol8/p1668-shukla.pdf

Comment: So the possible performance impact would be in the mapping of the JSON to Entity @Aravind Ramachandran

Comment: DocumentDB uses JSON.NET, you can compare performance to see for yourself, but in all likelihood it won't be a measurable difference.